# SQL minimum price with join several tables

Tags: sql-server, join, minimum

I'm using SQL Server 2008 and need to check the minimum price for each ordered product.  (2, 11, 15 is the `supplerid`)

This is the query:

```
SELECT 
   od.IDPRODUCTO, 
   p.NOMBRE AS DescProd, 
   t.MIN_PRICE, 
   t.IDLIBRERIA, 
   FECHAACTUALIZACION 
FROM   
   ORDERDETAILS od 
JOIN 
   (SELECT 
       rpl.IDPRODUCTO, 
       MIN(PRECIO) AS min_price, 
       rpl.IDLIBRERIA AS idlibreria 
    FROM   
       RELPRODUCTOLIBRERIAS rpl 
    GROUP BY 
       rpl.IDPRODUCTO, rpl.IDLIBRERIA) t ON t.IDPRODUCTO = Od.IDPRODUCTO 
JOIN 
    PRODUCTOS p ON (od.IDPRODUCTO = p.ID) 
LEFT JOIN 
    EDITORIALES e ON (p.IDEDITORIAL = e.ID) 
LEFT JOIN 
    ORDERSTATUSFOLLOWUP osf ON osf.ID = Od.IDSTATUSFOLLOWUP 
WHERE  
    IDORDER = 98770
```

Returns:

```
╔════════╦═══════════════════════╦════════╦════╦════════════╗
║ 153389 ║ CONCIENCIA- SOCIALES  ║ 165.00 ║ 11 ║ 2014-06-27 ║
║ 153389 ║ CONCIENCIA - SOCIALES ║ 165.00 ║ 15 ║ 2014-06-27 ║
║ 136892 ║ CUENTEME DON SEGUNDO  ║ 70.00  ║ 2  ║ 2014-06-27 ║
║ 136892 ║ CUENTEME DON SEGUNDO  ║ 50.00  ║ 11 ║ 2014-06-27 ║
║ 136892 ║ CUENTEME DON SEGUNDO  ║ 70.00  ║ 15 ║ 2014-06-27 ║
╚════════╩═══════════════════════╩════════╩════╩════════════╝
```

I need this result:

```
╔════════╦═══════════════════════╦════════╦════╦════════════╗
║ 153389 ║ CONCIENCIA - SOCIALES ║ 165.00 ║ 11 ║ 2014-06-27 ║
║ 136892 ║ CUENTEME DON SEGUNDO  ║ 50.00  ║ 11 ║ 2014-06-27 ║
╚════════╩═══════════════════════╩════════╩════╩════════════╝
```

What needs to be changed?

Thanks

Comment: If you include some sample data it is easier to understand the problem and easier to show you the solutions.

Comment: do you mean the original tables by sample data?

Comment: This or something close to it that will give us an idea of what you're dealing with

Comment: RELPRODUCTOLIBRERIAS has the supplier id, product id, supplier price. PRODUCTOS has the products/books..id,name. ORDERS has the general information for an order . ORDERDETAILS has the detailed information from an order. Please ignore the other tables. So suppose order ID 100, has 2 books purchased, so in orderdetails you would find 2 rows. I take one of those rows , idproduct ... and want to bring the BEST PRICE from table RELPRODUCTOLIBRERIAS (supplier price) and the idlibreria (ID from the bookstore) . So i know which bookstore has that book at the best price. same for the next product..

Comment: in my example results the $165 i dont mind if it brings 11 or 15 bookstore id, as both are $165....but on the second result i need idlibreria (bookstore id) 11 as that bookstor has the book at $50 (the best price)

Answer (score 2):

Try picking the min price and supplierID:

```
SELECT  od.IDProducto ,
        p.Nombre AS DescProd ,
        MIN(t.min_price) ,
        MIN(t.idlibreria) ,
        FechaActualizacion
FROM    orderdetails od
        JOIN ( SELECT   rpl.idproducto ,
                        MIN(precio) AS min_price ,
                        rpl.idlibreria AS idlibreria
               FROM     RelProductoLibrerias rpl
               GROUP BY rpl.idproducto ,
                        rpl.idlibreria
             ) t ON t.idproducto = Od.IDProducto
        JOIN Productos p ON ( od.IDProducto = p.ID )
        LEFT JOIN Editoriales e ON ( p.IdEditorial = e.Id )
        LEFT JOIN OrderStatusFollowUp osf ON osf.ID = Od.IDStatusFollowUp
WHERE   IDOrder = 98770
GROUP BY    od.IDProducto,
            p.Nombre,
            FechaActualizacion
```

Comment: this mixes the idlibreria with the minprice.... it does return $50 but it returns idlibreria 2 instead of 11 which corresponds to $50... this is because you are using min(idlibreria) ... so this does not work, thanks for your help, can you kindly help further? thanks!

Comment: The only way is to add a second or subselect to pull the correct idlibreria.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT       DISTINCT(od.IDProducto) , p.Nombre as DescProd,
         t.min_price,t.idlibreria,FechaActualizacion 
from         orderdetails od
join         (select    rpl.idproducto,min(precio) as min_price,rpl.idlibreria as idlibreria
         from       RelProductoLibrerias rpl 
         group by   rpl.idproducto ,rpl.idlibreria
         ) t 
on           t.idproducto = Od.IDProducto 
JOIN         Productos p ON (od.IDProducto = p.ID)
LEFT JOIN    Editoriales e ON (p.IdEditorial=e.Id)  
LEFT JOIN    OrderStatusFollowUp osf on osf.ID =  Od.IDStatusFollowUp WHERE IDOrder=98770
ORDER BY t.min_price
```

Comment: this returns all 5 results